# How to verify private method called in contructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have some code like this, and I want to verify the method "find" called:

```
public class Handler {

   public Handler(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException {
       var command = find(args);
       if (command == null) {
           var messageErr = "INVALID";
           throw new IllegalArgumentException(messageErr);
       }
       runCommand(command);
   }
  private boolean find(String[] args){
     if("valid".equal(args[0])) return true;
     return false;
  }
```

I has thought about PowerMock and write some code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(fullyQualifiedNames = "com.mypackage.*")
public class HandlerTest {
    private final String[] input = new String[]{"valid"};
    @Test
    public void shouldFindValidCommands() throws Exception {
        Handler handlerSpy = PowerMockito.spy(new Handler(input));
        doReturn(true).when(handlerSpy, "find", ArgumentMatchers.any(String[].class));
        Whitebox.invokeMethod(handlerSpy, "find");
        verifyPrivate(handlerSpy).invoke("find", input);
    }
```

but it gave me error:

```
No method found with name 'find' with parameter types: [ <none> ] in class com.mypackage.handler.Handler$MockitoMock$1535580467.
```

I cannot figure out how to verify that my private method was called.

Comment: As long as it isn't a new Java feature I am aware of, `find` doesn't have a return type and never returns `null`, therefore command can never be `null`. Also, the `String` class doesn't contain a method called `equal`. And you shouldn't even need a mock here. Your method is completely testable without a mock, as long as you stick to the values it can actually return...

Comment: sorry my bad, I just want to write a simple code for my actual situation ^^. I had fixed it

Comment: @maio290 I still don't understand how could it return the value when it is a private method(can't be called in test method)

Comment: Private means private. Don't check private methods. Check _the final behavior_, whether that is done with private methods or with inline code; in this case, by passing `valid` and not passing `valid` and confirming that the command is/is not run.

Comment: oh I can see that, thank you, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you basically want to do is the following:

```
   var command = find(args);
   if (!command ) { /* do stuff */}
```

The find function doesn't need a test to check whether it's called or not, since it is not working with anything on your class but rather always returns `true` or `false` or throws a `RuntimeException` when `args` is `null` or the `length` of `args` is `0`.

There is just no way (other than a JVM termination) that this function is not called when constructing a new `Object` of `Handler` - unless you're using the implicit no-args constructor. But in order to avoid this, you just add a private constructor:

```
private Handler()
{}
```

For your tests: You'd want to test the positive case somewhat like this:

```
@Test
public void shouldFindValidCommands() {
final String[] validInput = {"valid"};
Handler handler = new Handler(validInput);
}
```

For your negative test:

```
@Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
public void shouldThrowIllegalArgumentException() {
final String[] invalidInput = {"invalid"};
Handler handler = new Handler(invalidInput);
}
```